# Run 'app' with Code Coverage in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, code-coverage

There is a **Run with Coverage** button in Android Studio (Check attached image) , but it's always disabled, how can I enabled it?

[image]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to run a "junit" run configuration, like this one

[image: AS junit run configuration]

Only apply when you pass your unit tests